# Stackdriver alerts don't close automatically

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

Since June 2, we are seeing that some Stackdriver alerts do not close automatically. There are no way to close the alert manually, at least we don't see any way of close the alert through the panel. This carries a significant risk since, if once the problem is solved, the alert is still triggered, no alerts will be received for new problems.

Does anyone know if there is a way to close the alerts manually?

And does anyone know if this behabiour can be related with the recent BigQuery problems reported by Google Cloud? https://status.cloud.google.com/

Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

[**Closing incidents**](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/incidents-events#closing)
Incidents are closed automatically; you can't close an incident. An incident is closed when the system observed that the condition is no longer being met or when 7 days have passed without an observation that the condition is still being met.

Even though, you can "Aknowledge" them, which will basically let the system know that your are aware of it and will allow the alert to keep working as expected, otherwise, since the incident is opened, no new alert will be triggered in the meanwhile.

To [mark an incident as acknowledged](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/incidents-events#acking), do the following:

In the Incidents pane of the Alerting dashboard, click See all incidents.
On the Incidents page, find the incident that you want to acknowledge, and then do one of the following:

Click (3 vertical dots) More options and then select Acknowledge.
Open the details page for the incident and then click Acknowledge incident.

After Acknowledge the incident, open the still alerted incident and you should see a "Silence Incident" option, when you hit it, it will change the incident status to Closed.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply Jaime.
I know we can acknowledge the incidents, but if the incidents are not closed, alerts are not sent again.
On the other hand the problem is still the same, until now, incidents have been closed automatically, we don't know why now are not automatically closed.

Comment: After Acknowledge the incident, open the still alerted incident and you should see a "Silence Incident" option, when you hit it, it will change the incident status to Closed.

Comment: Thank you Jaime, as you say this close the incident and it seems that we are receiving notifications of new incidents.

On the other hand it would be great if someone knows why incidents are not closing automatically like they did until June 2.